# Can I control the installation of an android app database from Google Play Store?

Tags: android, installation

I have an app that has a database.
1) I need to save some tables from the current version before I load the app upgraded version.
2) I would like to save them as csv files.
3) Then after the app loads and database loads read those csv files into the new database
4) and then modify the tables with data from the new database.

I can do 3) and 4) by running some code after startup of the new version.
I can save the tables as csv but can I put 1) and 2) at the start of the install before the new database gets loaded?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can but I need to ask why save to csv? Installing an update to an App from the store will not delete the local installed database. You can indicate in your`SQLiteOpenHelper` implementation that the DB version is new and then in the onUpgrade hook run any SQL or other tasks to 'migrate'(upgrade) the database.

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  if(oldVersion <= 29 && newVersion >= 30) {
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE mytable ADD phone_number;");
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and for the `SQLiteOpenHelper`  `public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {`  I found exactly what you were saying in my database.  It was sitting there commented out and waiting for me.